# create xml from xmltype using xmlsequence(cursor)

Tags: xml, oracle

I have this xml query running against a **view**: (oracle 11g r1)

```
select xmlelement("clientid", xmlattributes (a.clientid),
                               (select xmlagg(
                                              xmlelement("plan",
                                                 xmlattributes(b.planid,b.planame),
                                                    xmlagg( xmlelement ("ppt", xmlattributes ( b.pname, b.pdname)
     )))) from **viewname** b
           where b.clientid = a.clientid
            group by b.planid,b.planname)) as xmlfrom **viewname** a group by a.clientid;
```

Is it possible to run this against an xmlsequence(cursor) instead of a view? i.e.

```
select xmlelement("clientid", xmlattributes (a.clientid),
                               (select xmlagg(
                                              xmlelement("plan",
                                                 xmlattributes(b.planid,b.planame),
                                                    xmlagg( xmlelement ("ppt", xmlattributes ( b.pname, b.pdname)
     )))) from **table(xmlsequence(cursor))** b
           where b.clientid = a.clientid
            group by b.planid,b.planname)) as xml from **table(xmlsequence(cursor))** a group by a.clientid;
```

or is there another way to do this?
My oracle xml stuff is really lacking so I apologize if my question is newb-ish...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a solution but if i want make an xml i am doinig like this:

I am declaring cursor:

```
CURSOR cur(l_date_od date, l_date_do date) IS
    select ... from .. where ...;
```

I am declaring cursor row type

```
 variable cur%ROWTYPE;
```

And selecting into xml_type variable each row

```
open cur(local_date1,local_date2);
  loop
  fetch linia into variable ;
  exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
  select xmlelement("ROW", 
            xmlelement("VENDOR_SITE_CODE",variable .VENDOR_SITE_CODE ),
            xmlelement("ATTRIBUTE1",variable .ATTRIBUTE1 ),
            xmlelement("INVOICE_NUM",variable .INVOICE_NUM ),
            xmlelement("INVOICE_DATE",variable .INVOICE_DATE )
            )
        into xml_type_variable
        FROM dual;
        xml_file2 :=(xml_file.getClobVal()); ----Here i am conversing to clob
  end loop;
  close linia;
```